# For exploring something

Tags: grammar

Is "for exploring space" a correct construction?

"They have to create international programs for exploring space and create international universities connected with the space programs."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Programs for exploring space*" is fine. The other option would be "*programs to explore space*". The difference is whether you want to state *reason* or *purpose*.

For example:

- I bought a pan for cooking eggs (cooking eggs is the *purpose* of the pan)
- I bought a pan to cook eggs (cooking eggs is the *reason* you bought the pan)

Likewise:

- They have to create international programs for exploring space.

This would mean that the purpose of the programs is space exploration, and 'they' have to create this kind of program.

- They have to create international programs to explore space.

This would mean 'they' have to explore space, and must create programs in order to achieve that.